# Specify time zone for viewing information in azure portal?

Tags: azureportal

When I am using portal.azure.com to check on various resources, it is not clear which time zone the information is being displayed in.

Is there anyway to set a time zone for your entire account so you know what time zone is being used?

Is the time zone displayed the one the resource is located in, the time zone I am viewing it from, UTC, something else entirely?

Answer (score -2):

There is a service named **Azure Policy** may meet your need.

You can use policy to [add a tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies#tags) including created time value to every resources under your subscription.

About including created utc time, you can refer to this and modify your own code:

```
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
      "exists": "false"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ],
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "add",
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "value": "[utcNow()]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
      },
      "defaultValue": "CreatedTime"
    }
  }
}
```